# Prevent second button click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button on my page. I don't want to do any operation if the user clicks on the button for second time. I have the following code. But it is not working. Can someone help??

```
      $("#myButton").click(function(){
        var count = 0;
        count++;
        alert("button");
        if(count>1)
          $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
     });
     <button type="button" id="myButton" > Click Me </button>
```

This is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7jCwK/1/)

Comment: @Barmar He would never disable it - he's declaring and assigning `count = 0` inside the event handler.

Comment: .one is best solution - however as barmar just said simply change `if(count>1)` to `if(count > 0)` and that would also work!

Comment: Yeah, realized that after I saw some of the latest answers. But even if he moves the initialization outside, his counting is wrong.

Comment: The counter isn't even needed if you want to disable it on the first click. You only need a counter for more than 1.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) in jquery for that

```
$("#myButton").one("click",function(){
```

It will attach a handler to an event for the element which will executed at most one.

Comment: look at all the snipers above! glad you got most votes!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Half of the other answers (below if you sort by oldest) were posted at the same time :)

Comment: sorting by oldest you are number 1 - all others are mere mortals in comparison to your fast fingers!

Answer (score 3):

Change this...

```
  $("#myButton").click(function(){
      var count = 0;
      count++;
      alert("button");
      if(count>1)
          $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
  });
```

to this...

```
  $("#myButton").one("click", function(){
      alert("button");
  });
```

That assigns a click event handler that will only fire the first time you click the element, in this case your button.

You could have altered your existing code very minimally to make it work...

```
  var count = 0;
  $("#myButton").click(function(){
      count++;
      alert("button");
      if(count>0)
          $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
  });
```

The way you had it you were setting count to 0 every time you clicked the button (and also only disabling the button after 2 clicks).

Comment: lol @ the downvote for a clear and correct answer.  I don't even.

Answer (score 1):

use `.one()` to bind event to run/execute once.

```
 $("#myButton").one('click',function(){
    alert("button");
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7jCwK/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do that [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jCwK/4/)

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    alert("button");
    $(this).unbind();
});
```

Comment: You can use `$(this).unbind()`

Comment: Internally the `.one` should do something like this... Can anyone confirm this? (i mean implementation wise)

Answer (score 0):

Use `off()`

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    var count = 0;
    count++;
    alert("button");
    $(this).off('click');

    if(count>1)
      $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked = false;
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    if(!clicked){
        clicked = true;
        alert("button");
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }               
 });
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7jCwK/6/

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your `count` var on click of everytime. move this outside and see working

```
  var count = 0; 
$("#myButton").click(function(){

     count++;
    alert("button");
     if(count>0)
         $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jCwK/16/)

Comment: alert is displayed on second click

Answer (score 0):

`Diasble` button once you click button first time

Check the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/chetangawai/7jCwK/10/

Comment: Include the code to your answer, not just a fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

declare

```
  var count = 0;
```

outside from click function

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7jCwK/9/)

```
   var count = 0;

   $("#myButton").click(function(){

      count++;

      alert("button");

      if(count>=1)

          $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

Your variable gets initialized every time a function is called, you can use variable outside function.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with actually disabling the button particularly when performing a form submission. Because disabling the button prevents further actions, what you might try is adding a class to the button on click that is called "disabled" and then use a handler for the new "disabled" class to prevent default behavior on click using something like:

```
$(".my_submit_button").click(function(e){
    $(e.target).addClass("disabled");
})

$(".disabled").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This should allow the button to complete any actions from the first click (even if that action was a form submission) while still disallowing any subsequent clicks.

Answer (score -3):

Try this and pl avoid using just "click" instead use "on", below code show how the click is manipulated by its alternate.

```
 $("#myButton").on("click" , function(){

      $("#myButton").off("click"); //just off the click event once u click
        var count = 0;
         count++;
        alert("button");
        var isBool = count>1;
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', isBool);

    });
```

check the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7jCwK/13/

Comment: `Click` is a jQuery wrapper for `on("click")` so there is no difference whatsoever.  You are defining and initialising `count` every time, so it will never be greater than 0.  You are also creating a boolean variable to store a value in that is only used once in the function, therefore it's no needed.  You've basically overcomplicated an already incorrect piece of code.

Comment: @Archer How could u say the code is incorrect i suggested that to use on instead of click so no prob yet we may also use click and put off to stop clicking second tym, and boolean variable returns false r true to store in varable that affects to button disable anyway its doesn't increment uncless clicking for the 2nd tym..now wats ur problem .

Comment: Excessive, unnecessary code that is all 100% pointless.  If you have `off("click")` then the button click event handler will never run again.  You declare count to be 0 EVERY TIME THAT CODE IS RUN, so it will *NEVER* be > 1 (which would only happen the 3rd time the code runs anyway).  This is totally incorrect and misleading and should be deleted.