# How to prevent click event on second times on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few buttons, when I click on those buttons some `divs` are creating automatically, but here I need to prevent to create any div when I click on next time on the same button on which I already clicked.

Code is below

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
    <button id="append">button1</button>
    <button id="append">button2</button>
    <button id="append">button3</button>
    <div id="parent"></div>
</div>
```

### SCRIPT

```
(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#parent').append('<div id="first'+count+'">text</div>');
        count++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent second button click using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269292/prevent-second-button-click-using-jquery)

Comment: it is not  duplicate as the refrence quesction is different from this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method. This binds a handler that only runs once for each element.

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('button').one("click", function() {
    $('#parent').append('<div id="first' + count + '">text</div>');
    count++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
  <button id="append">button1</button> <button id="append">button2</button> <button id="append">button3</button>
  <div id="parent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here in my project I am using delegate method with click,so how  to handle in that case.I tried with delegate but not working

Answer (score 0):

Just unbind it after first click.

```
$(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $('button').click(function(){
    count = Number($(this).data('click')||0);
    if(count>0){
       $(this).unbind("click");
    }

    count = count+1;
    $(this).data('click',count);         

    $('#parent').append('<div id="first'+count+'">text</div>');
  });
});
```

Comment: here only first time div is creating,when I click different button  div is not creating again,actually my requirement is not to create any div when I click on same button(already clicked)  out of 3 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is creating click flag.
Flag is set to **true** once clicked and set to **false** if action is finished.
The action should be performed only if flag is **false**.

Like this:

```
(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var flag = false;

    $('button').click(function(){
        if(flag) return false; // Disable when action is on

        // Action starts
        flag = true;
        $('#parent').append('<div id="first'+count+'">text</div>');
        count++;

        // Action ends
        flag = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: now  div is not creating onclick of any button,actually my requirement is not to create any div when I click on same button(already clicked) out of 3 buttons else div will be creating until I click on same button which already clicked

Answer (score 0):

Here are three possible solutions:

1. Disable the button that was clicked by adding `$(this).attr('disabled',true);` inside anonymous click function.
2. Adding a data-enabled attribute to the buttons and checking it. Your HTML for a button becomes like this: `<button id="append" data-enabled="true">button1</button>` and then you add this to the anonymous click function:

   ```
   (function(){
     var count = 0;
     $('button').click(function(){
       if ( $(this).data('enabled') == 'false' ) return;
       else
       {
           $(this).data('enabled', 'false');
           $('#parent').append('<div id="first'+count+'">text</div>'); 
           count++;
       }
     });
   });
   ```
3. Create an array that with the button as keys and their enabled/disabled boolean value as their value and refer to that in the anonymous click function.

Answer (score 0):

1- Your code needs a `$` in first of your `js` to calling it after `document.ready`: `$(function(){...})`, or adding `()` at end of it for calling Immediately (`(function(){...})();`).

2- You can use `off` to remove a listener from an element.

other things is ok in your code. please look at result:

```js
$(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#parent').append('<div id="first'+count+'">text</div>');
    count++;
    $(this).off("click");//One of benefits of this way is: you can add some conditions for removing this event. > if(...) $(this).off("click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
<button id="append">button1</button> <button id="append">button2</button> <button id="append">button3</button>
<div id="parent"></div>
</div>
```